# What is the difference between model and model._doc in mongoose Models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm new to java script and I'm building a graphql API with mongoose 
and when I want to return a result of myModel.find() using mongoose I see that there is a difference between model and model._doc .
in this code

```
return {
    ...model._doc
}
```

everything is OK and can get the result 
but when I code like this

```
return{
    ...model
}
```

I get an error when I want to retrieve the data.
when I print them they are exactly the same as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model` object is a mongoose object and not a normal JSON object, and to get data from the model object you should use `toJSON` method.

`_doc` is an internal property and you shouldn't be using it, if they changed it your application will break.

```
model.toJSON()
```

Comment: Because it's not in the mongoose API, which means if they changed it your application will break!

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot.